# SQL between logic

Tags: mysql

[image]

Given that I wanted to list the names and prices of venues within an inclusive  minimum and maximum capacity (i.e. greater than and equal to/less than and equal to) would using the below SQL statement suffice? Is there a better way of presenting it?

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE capacity between '$minimum' AND '$maximum'
```

I was just wondering because it confuses me slightly.

If minimum is 0 and maximum is 1000 – what would be the logic behind SQL’s selection of rows that meet the statements criteria?

Comment: I believe that your statement will do the job - just ensure that the first value is the lowest and after the `AND` is the highest. Further reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between According to MySQL reference, between is another way of `>= $val1 AND <= $val2` +1 for SC2 buildings too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. See [§11.3.2 "Comparison Functions and Operators" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) for an explanation of how `BETWEEN` works; as you can see, it does provide an inclusive minimum and maximum, just as you need.

That said, although your query is perfectly correct as it is, it might be better to change `'$minimum' AND '$maximum'` to `$minimum AND $maximum` (no quotation marks), just so it's visually clear that these are numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that would work fine to me, but I'm not sure what you're confused about. The "between" criterion selects everything from $minimum to $maximum, inclusive, just like you said.

According to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp), some (unnamed) databases implement BETWEEN as exclusive instead of inclusive (that is, it won't select values that are equal to $minimum or $maximum). So it might be safer to replace your criterion with two explicit inequalities instead:

```
where capacity >= $minimum and capacity <= $maximum
```

Comment: This is tagged as MySQL though. However, with that point aside, I am always wary of the accuracy of W3Schools. Although it does host a wealth of good information, it also provides a lot of incorrect information. See http://w3fools.com/ for more reading.

Comment: True, but if you write it using an appropriate abstraction layer, someone might always decide to port it to another database someday. But maybe that's totally implausible given your circumstances. Thanks for the link, anyway.